# Replacing one object out of two, how does it work?

Tags: mesh, objects, shortcut

I have a character out of 3 parts, i pressed cntrl p and made it to one object.
Now I want to replace one cube with these three parts. I tried cntrl l and i tried it with the properties menu but it doesnt work either. Sorry I come from Germany, so my english not good but I hope you are able to understand me anyway.

So thank you

Comment: Please clarify your question. Ctrl+P Parents an object to another. They stay seperate objekts.

Comment: Sure but i thought that could help... so how can i replace one object with two or three or four... other objects? For example i have one cube and this cube i want to replace with a group of objects like two circles. In blender game engine

Comment: ...i have the simple things like movement and so on binded to a cube so now how can i replace that cube with my game char which is out of three parts so that the movement keeps

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You mention the Game Engine in the comments but nowhere in the question and tags. What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Please edit your question and clearly state your intentions with some screenshots of your scene

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I made the three meshes together by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> so that it is one object and then I replaced it with the cube. Then I went to edit mode and selected one part and pressed <kbd>P</kbd> and chose selected. It's again a separated mesh.